# Get IP address and port in Flask decorator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

How to get in a decorator function in Flask the IP address and port of the client that sent the request ?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from functools import wraps
app = Flask(__name__)

def check_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        ###  Here I need the IP address and port of the client
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
@check_auth
def hello():
    json = request.json
    json['nm'] = 'new name2'
    jsonStr = jsonify(json)
    return jsonStr
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Flask's `request.environ()` function to get the Remote port and IP Address for the client:

```
from flask import request
from functools import wraps

def check_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        ###  Here I need the IP address and port of the client
        print("The client IP is: {}".format(request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        print("The client port is: {}".format(request.environ['REMOTE_PORT']))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

The decorator prints something like:

```
The client IP is: 127.0.0.1
The client port is: 12345
```